# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FSYNCED

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, kotlin, micronaut, hibernate-ogm

I am getting error when executing below code, could you please help me in resolving this error

```
public fun getEntityManager(): EntityManager {
    val tm: TransactionManager = com.arjuna.ats.jta.TransactionManager.transactionManager()
  
    val emf: EntityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
            "mongo-ogm")
    tm.begin()
   return emf.createEntityManager()
}
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: FSYNCED
at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.options.WriteConcernType.(WriteConcernType.java:37)
at org.hibernate.ogm.datastore.mongodb.options.impl.WriteConcernOption.(WriteConcernOption.java:29)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)
at org.hibernate.ogm.options.navigation.source.impl.ConfigurationOptionValueSource$ConfigurationBasedOptionContainer.getAll(ConfigurationOptionValueSource.
java:82)

```
<persistence-unit name="mongo-ogm" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence</provider>

    <class>com.ogm.model.UserEntity</class>
    <properties>
        
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.provider" value="mongodb"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.datastore.database" value="demo"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.host" value="localhost"/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.username" value=""/>
        <property name="hibernate.ogm.mongodb.password" value=""/>
      <!--  <property name="" value="localhost"/>-->
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem"/>
        <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/tmp/.hibernate_ogm_demo_luceneindexes"/>
    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

```
implementation("org.hibernate.ogm:hibernate-ogm-mongodb:5.4.1.Final")
implementation("org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-reactivestreams:4.0.5")
implementation("org.jboss.narayana.jta:narayana-jta:5.8.1.Final")
implementation("org.jboss:jboss-transaction-spi:7.6.0.Final")
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this issue occurs when you have dependency mismatch.
I suspect you have more than one version of hibernate-ogm-mongodb in you classpath.

`hibernate-ogm-mongodb:5.4.1.Final` contains enum `WriteConcernType.FSYNCED(WriteConcern.FSYNCED)`

1. Run `gradle dependencies | grep hibernate-ogm-mongodb`, verify if you have more than one version of the library as dependency.
2. Exclude older/other versions from other dependencies in your `build.gradle` file.